# Why is it necessary to remove a column for running ridge and lasso in R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to run my own ridge regression/ lasso and I am modeling my approach on an example on page 251 of "An Introduction to Statistical Learning". We are told to set up the model matrix as follows:

```
library(ISLR)
x=model.matrix(Salary∼.,Hitters)[,-1] 
y=Hitters$Salary
```

My question is: Why is it necessary to remove a column as per "[,-1]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be certain as I cannot see the rest of the code, but the purpose of `model.matrix()` is to redesign your input data so that it is ready to be processed by a regression model. It does things like transform any factors into a set of dummy variables.

When this function is run, it creates an extra `(Intercept)` column in column `1` so my guess is that they are removing this column because the subsequent model (say,  `glm()`) does not require this extra column.